# I am having a hard time publishing a project on github or kaggle

Tags: kaggle, github-for-windows

I am completely new to the IT world and I'm working on a Google Data Analytics Certificate. I'm almost done but I just need to publish my project. I have tried Kaggle and Github and hit a wall on both. The instructions given were not clear and it seems like they are for older versions. I just need some help to get started because I am completely lost.

I've got as far as setting up an account on both platforms. Not much done after that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.